# Debugging Geddy Node.js application in Windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, signals, node-inspector, geddy

Is there a way to debug Geddy.js (a Node.js framework) applications under Windows?

There is a [wiki page](https://github.com/mde/geddy/wiki/Debugging) on their site about debugging with `node-inspector` but I guess it won't work on Windows, because it uses signals:

```
kill -s USR1 3180
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use WebStorm or IntelliJ as mentioned on the [Debugging Wiki Page](https://github.com/mde/geddy/wiki/Debugging). Other IDEs might work with a similar configuration.

I tried starting it with the debugger, but I get as far as debugging geddy. You can give it a go. The signal is only needed if the process was started without the debugger, however you can run the following command:

`node --debug /usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/bin/cli.js`
or 
`node --debug-brk /usr/local/lib/node_modules/geddy/bin/cli.js`

I also found [node-inspector-windows](https://github.com/glennblock/node-inspector-windows) looks promising, but I've not tried it.

Answer (score 2):

I use Webstorm to develop and debug geddy. You need to write a server starting script that launches the geddy server with no workers like so:

```
var geddy = require('geddy');

if (geddy.isMaster) {
    geddy.config({
        environment: 'development'
        , workers: 0
    }); 
}   

geddy.start();
```

Just have WebStorm run "node start.js" [which is the script above] and you can add breakpoints etc.